# How many monks required to ordain or create new Sangha?

Tags: vinaya

How many monks does it take to ordain a new monk? How many monks does it take to create a new Sangha?

I've read this before, now I can't find it.

I think these are very old rules & are similar across different traditions.

**Note**. I already know that schism is considered the worst thing in the universe by traditional Buddhism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quorum of 10 of 10 years standing, 5 in border areas. 5 is the quorum generally outside India. [page 108, [Theravada Buddhism: A Social History from Ancient Benares to Modern Colombo (The Library of Religious Beliefs and Practices)](http://www.ahandfulofleaves.org/documents/Theravada%20Buddhism_Gombrich.pdf) 2nd Edition
by Richard F. Gombrich]

The quorum to perform a *patimokkha* ceremony is 4 [page 110, [Theravada Buddhism: A Social History from Ancient Benares to Modern Colombo (The Library of Religious Beliefs and Practices)](http://www.ahandfulofleaves.org/documents/Theravada%20Buddhism_Gombrich.pdf) 2nd Edition
by Richard F. Gombrich]